# Error when launching the emulator in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

When I run my program it sais:

"Unfortunately your App has stopped!"

This is the console

```
[2013-04-10 18:36:09 - STO App] ------------------------------
[2013-04-10 18:36:09 - STO App] Android Launch!
[2013-04-10 18:36:09 - STO App] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-10 18:36:09 - STO App] Performing sarah.bodoor.sto.Reminder activity launch
[2013-04-10 18:36:09 - STO App] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'STODevice' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2013-04-10 18:36:11 - STO App] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-04-10 18:36:11 - STO App] Starting activity sarah.bodoor.sto.Reminder on device emulator-5554
[2013-04-10 18:36:14 - STO App] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=sarah.bodoor.sto/.Reminder }
```

This is the logCat

```
04-10 15:57:00.324: E/Trace(1977): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test2/com.example.test2.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5614)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5756)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(FrameLayout.java:610)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:554)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.generateLayoutParams(FrameLayout.java:56)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at com.example.test2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977):     ... 11 more
```

Even  when I do a simple project as a test it gave me the same message. What should I do?

Comment: you should show us some code...

Comment: Please post you code and Logcat, then only we can help. Your console shows that everything is working as expected\

Comment: Look into `logcat`. If your app stopped because it threw an exception, you can see what that is there.

Comment: I added my log cat now

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory - 04-10 15:57:01.565: E/AndroidRuntime(1977): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test2/com.example.test2.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a layout_width attribute:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #16: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

add layout_width attribute in the XML file will resolve the problem.